# Pandas groupby time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, large-data

I have two dataframes. DF1 contains the following:

> User |   Time interval
>
> User01  | [01/01/2014 08:12:00, 01/01/2014 08:13:43]
>
> User02  | [01/03/2014 07:21:44, 01/04/2014 01:07:01]

DF 2 contains events:

> User | Time | Value
>
> User01 | 01/03/2014 04:11:00 | 9
>
> User01 | 01/01/2014 08:10:00 | 12
>
> User02 | 01/03/2014 09:11:00 | 3
>
> User02 | 01/02/2014 011:10:00 | 21

I want to add 3 columns to DF1, containing mean, standard deviation and max values for each user within the time interval, based on the events in DF2.

So the final result should look like this:

> User |   Time interval | Mean | Max | StDev
>
> User01  | [01/01/2014 08:12:00, 01/01/2014 08:13:43] | NaN | NaN | Nan
>
> User02  | [01/03/2014 07:21:44, 01/04/2014 01:07:01] | 3 | 3 | 0

What is an efficient way to do this if my tables are large? Is there some sort of "groupby" function for time intervals that are based on another dataframe?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'User' : pd.Series(["User01", "User02"], index=['1', '2']), 'Time start' : pd.Series(["01/01/2014 08:12:00", "01/03/2014 07:21:44"], index=['1', '2']),'Time end' : pd.Series(["01/01/2014 08:13:43", "01/04/2014 01:07:01"], index=['1', '2'])})

DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'User' : pd.Series(["User01","User01","User02", "User02"], index=['1', '2','3','4']), 'Time' : pd.Series(["01/03/2014 04:11:00", "01/01/2014 08:10:00","01/03/2014 09:11:00","01/02/2014 011:10:00"], index=['1', '2','3', '4']),'Value' : pd.Series([9,12,3,21], index=['1', '2','3','4'])})

DF3 = pd.DataFrame({'User' : pd.Series(["User01", "User02"], index=['1', '2']), 'Time start' : pd.Series(["01/01/2014 08:12:00", "01/03/2014 07:21:44"], index=['1', '2']),'Time end' : pd.Series(["01/01/2014 08:13:43", "01/04/2014 01:07:01"], index=['1', '2']),'Mean' : pd.Series(["Nan", 3], index=['1', '2']),'Max' : pd.Series(["Nan", 3], index=['1', '2']),'StDev' : pd.Series(["Nan", 0], index=['1', '2'])})
```

Comment: It's helpful to have copy-pasteable examples. Also post what your expected solution should look like with the examples you gave. This should be doable by splitting your `Time interval` column into two, a low and high end, and then using something like `between_time` on the second dataframe.

Comment: Thanks. Can you specify what you mean by copy pasteable example?

Comment: You say what your dataframes look like but you don't supply code for creating them. This means anybody trying to help you will first have to write code to create these dataframes. It's a lot easier to copy and paste your code to get to the same point you are now, than to waste time trying to recreate your data structures. Try doing df.to_dict() on your objects, then post code like `DF1 = pandas.DataFrame({'User': ...})` etc instead of just describing what you have in words.

Comment: First you should clean up your frames, a good start is extract the start and end of your time intervals as datetime columns. It's not clear whether Users are unique (do you only care about there behaviour in one time interval? if so, that makes things easier.)

Comment: Got it. Added the code to generate the DFs. Separated start and end time too. Looking at between_time now.

Comment: It seems that between_time only works for times, and not datetimes. Is there another trick that allows me to keep only rows between datetimes?

Comment: This question has been asked a few times. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31052376/average-over-a-specific-time-period/31053345?noredirect=1#31053345) is an example I've been involved with, which has a couple of answers.

Answer (score -1):

First, merge the DF1 and DF2

```
df = DF2.merge(DF1,on="User")
```

and create an indicator ("keep") if time falls between time start and time ends

```
import numpy as np
df.loc[:,"keep"] = (np.logical_and(df.loc[:,"Time start"]<=df.loc[:,"Time"],df.loc[:,"Time"]<=df.loc[:,"Time end"]))*1
```

Output:

```
    Time                User  Value Time end            Time start       keep
 2014-01-03 04:11:00    User01  9   2014-01-01 08:13:43 2014-01-01 08:12:00 0
 2014-01-01 08:10:00    User01  12  2014-01-01 08:13:43 2014-01-01 08:12:00 0
 2014-01-03 09:11:00    User02  3   2014-01-04 01:07:01 2014-01-03 07:21:44 1
 2014-01-02 11:10:00    User02  21  2014-01-04 01:07:01 2014-01-03 07:21:44 0
```

Now only keep the rows where keep=1

```
df = df.loc[df.keep==1,:]
```

Now do the aggrgation on df using groupby

```
df4 = df.groupby("User")["Value"].agg(['max','mean','std']).reset_index()
```

output:

```
    User    max mean    std
    User02  3   3   NaN
```

merge df4 with DF1

```
DF1.merge(df4.reset_index(), on="User",how="left")
```

output:

```
 Time end           Time start          User    max mean std
2014-01-01 08:13:43 2014-01-01 08:12:00 User01  NaN NaN NaN
2014-01-04 01:07:01 2014-01-03 07:21:44 User02  3.0 3.0 NaN
```

Comment: Person who downvoted my answer please let me know why? so that I can help you with it.