# Average over a specific time period

Tags: python, pandas

I have a quite huge table in python from a .h5 file
The start of the table looks somewhat like this:

```
table =
                [WIND REL DIRECTION  [deg]]  [WIND SPEED  [kts]]  \
735381.370833                            0             0.000000   
735381.370845                            0             0.000000   
735381.370880                            0             0.000000   
735381.370891                            0             0.000000   
735381.370903                            0             0.000000   
735381.370972                            0             0.000000   
735381.370984                            0             0.000000   
735381.370995                            0             0.000000   
735381.371007                            0             0.000000   
735381.371019                            0             0.000000   
...
```

The index line is the timestamp of the data. I need to take calculate the avarage WIND REL SPEED and WIND SPEED every 15th second, and turn this into one row. I really need to do this in an efficient way, this .h5 file is huge.

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.dates as pltd
import tables

pltd.num2date(table.index) #to turn the timestamp into a date
```

I am quite clueless here, all help is appreciated.

Comment: At risk of being a "we know best" type person, it doesn't sound like a good idea to put the average speeds in as a new row. That way your column `WIND SPEED` contains two different types of information. Recipe for disaster in my book.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for my english, i wasnt planing on putting the avarage inbetween the wind speed that are there already, i was either planing to delete the 15 first seconds then put the avarage in, or make a new table with the avarages.

Comment: As discussed in the comments to the currently 2 available answers: The current answers seem to produce the correct results for the windspeed, but both produce unreasonable results for the winddirection, which need special treatment as it represents circular data. The average winddirection of 2° and 358° is 360° (or 0°), but not 180°, what would be the arithmetic mean.

Answer (score 2):

[`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) is your friend.

```
idx = pltd.num2date(table.index)
df = pd.DataFrame({'direction': np.random.randn(10), 
                   'speed': np.random.randn(10)}, 
                  index=idx)

>>> df
                                  direction     speed
2014-05-28 08:53:59.971204+00:00   0.205429  0.699439
2014-05-28 08:54:01.008002+00:00   0.383199 -0.392261
2014-05-28 08:54:04.031995+00:00  -2.146569 -0.325526
2014-05-28 08:54:04.982402+00:00   1.572352  1.289276
2014-05-28 08:54:06.019200+00:00   0.880394 -0.440667
2014-05-28 08:54:11.980795+00:00  -1.343758  0.615725
2014-05-28 08:54:13.017603+00:00  -1.713043  0.552017
2014-05-28 08:54:13.968000+00:00  -0.350017  0.728910
2014-05-28 08:54:15.004798+00:00  -0.619273  0.286762
2014-05-28 08:54:16.041596+00:00   0.459747  0.524788

>>> df.resample('15S', how='mean') # how='mean' is the default here
                           direction     speed
2014-05-28 08:53:45+00:00   0.205429  0.699439
2014-05-28 08:54:00+00:00  -0.388206  0.289639
2014-05-28 08:54:15+00:00  -0.079763  0.405775
```

Performance is similar to the method provided by @LondonRob.  I used a DataFrame with 1 million rows to test.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'direction': np.random.randn(1e6), 'speed': np.random.randn(1e6)}, index=pd.date_range(start='2015-1-1', periods=1e6, freq='1S'))

>>> %timeit df.resample('15S')
100 loops, best of 3: 15.6 ms per loop

>>> %timeit df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='15S')).mean()
100 loops, best of 3: 15.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: It is calculating mean values in 15 second buckets.  Note the bucket sizes are 1, 7 and 2.

Comment: The `TimeGrouper` method and the `resample` method produce identical results. Yours is probably the cooler of the two because it's a proper built-in part of the `DataFrame` API. (I've timed them and the speeds are identical.)

Comment: The only thing I'd say in "defence" of the `TimeGrouper` method is that it makes it identical to the non-time-series case: `groupby` then `mean`. That's probably a plus point.

Comment: Same comment for this answer: 
Be carfeul. The arithmetic mean of winddirection is probably not what you want. (2+358)/2 = 160. That is probably Not what you expect.

Comment: True about the result, no idea what came to my head. It was also just a warning that this is the correct result for the windspeed, but at the same time it produces nonsense for the wind direction. Not necessarily directed towards you, but rather to the OP.

Comment: mind that in  pandas 1.2.1 there is no  `how` parameter -- rather use df.resample(M, on=week_starting).mean()

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the "right" way to do this. (Although it seems a little bit underdocumented to me. Anyway it works!)

You need to do a `groupby` on your DataFrame and use something called a `TimeGrouper`.

It works like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a dataframe. You can ignore all this bit!
periods = 60 * 60
random_dates = pd.date_range('2015-12-25', periods=periods, freq='s')
random_speeds = np.random.randint(100, size=periods)
random_directions = np.random.random(periods)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': random_dates, 'wind_speed': random_speeds, 'wind_direction': random_directions})
df = df.set_index('date')

# Here's where the magic happens:
grouped15s = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='15S'))
averages_ws_15s = grouped15s.wind_speed.mean()
```

Or, if you insist on having spaces in your column names, that last line will become:

```
averages_ws_15s = grouped15s['Wind Speed'].mean()
```

This results in the following:

```
date
2015-12-25 00:00:00    45.800000
2015-12-25 00:00:15    48.466667
2015-12-25 00:00:30    38.066667
2015-12-25 00:00:45    54.866667
2015-12-25 00:01:00    34.866667
2015-12-25 00:01:15    37.000000
2015-12-25 00:01:30    47.133333
etc....                etc....
```

Comment: Be carfeul. The arithmetic mean of winddirection is probably not what you want. (2+358)/2 = 160. That is probably Not what you expect.

Comment: @Nras, did you come up with a solution for the 15s average wind direction?

Comment: @squar_o yes, the key is to use circular statistics. You can sum op the sin, cosine values of those angles to get the final sine/cosine values for the average angle. Then transform back to an angle between 0 and 360 degree.
``rads = np.deg2rad(direction), s = np.arctan2(np.sum(np.sin(rads)), np.sum(np.cos(rads))), mean_direction = (np.rad2deg(s) + 360) % 360``