# Pandas: Calculate average of values for a time frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on a large datasets that looks like this:

```
Time,   Value
01.01.2018 00:00:00.000,  5.1398
01.01.2018 00:01:00.000,  5.1298
01.01.2018 00:02:00.000,  5.1438
01.01.2018 00:03:00.000,  5.1228
01.01.2018 00:04:00.000,  5.1168
.... , ,,,,
31.12.2018 23:59:59.000,  6.3498
```

The data is a `minute` data from the `first` day of the year to the `last` day of the year

I want to use `Pandas` to find the average of every `5` days.

For example:

Average from `01.01.2018 00:00:00.000` to `05.01.2018 23:59:59.000` is average for `05.01.2018`

The next average will be from `02.01.2018 00:00:00.000` to `6.01.2018 23:59:59.000` is average for `06.01.2018`

The next average will be from `03.01.2018 00:00:00.000` to `7.01.2018 23:59:59.000` is average for `07.01.2018`

and so on... We are incrementing day by 1 but calculating an average from the day to past 5days, including the current date.

> For a given day, there are 24hours * 60minutes =  1440 data points. So I need to get the average of 1440 data points * 5 days = 7200 data points.

The final DataFrame will look like this, time format [DD.MM.YYYY] (without hh:mm:ss) and the `Value` is the average of 5 data including the current date:

```
Time,   Value
05.01.2018,  5.1398
06.01.2018,  5.1298
07.01.2018,  5.1438
.... , ,,,,
31.12.2018,  6.3498
```

The bottom line is to calculate the average of data from today to the past 5 days and the average value is shown as above.

I tried to iterate through Python loop but I wanted something better than we can do from Pandas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Average over a specific time period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31052376/average-over-a-specific-time-period)

Comment: @Valentino the solution does not work, because what I want at the end solution is different. The `duplicate` answers calculate for every next `15s` but what I want is to calculate every day for the next 5. We are not skipping a day as stated in the question.

Comment: @Alexander - Good question. First 4 data will be NAN since there is no number to take average because we are doing 5 number average.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, is not a duplicate of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will work?

```
import numpy as np

# Create one year of random data spaced evenly in 1 minute intervals.
np.random.seed(0)  # So that others can reproduce the same result given the random numbers.
time_idx = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2018-12-31', freq='min')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': time_idx, 'Value': abs(np.random.randn(len(time_idx))) + 5})

>>> df.shape
(524161, 2)
```

Given the dataframe with 1 minute intervals, you can take a rolling average over the past five days (5 days * 24 hours/day * 60 minutes/hour = 7200 minutes) and assign the result to a new column named `rolling_5d_avg`.  You can then group on the original timestamps using the `dt` accessor method to grab the date, and then take the last `rolling_5d_avg` value for each date.

```
df = (
    df
    .assign(rolling_5d_avg=df.rolling(window=5*24*60)['Value'].mean())
    .groupby(df['Time'].dt.date)['rolling_5d_avg']
    .last()
)

>>> df.head(10)
Time
2018-01-01         NaN
2018-01-02         NaN
2018-01-03         NaN
2018-01-04         NaN
2018-01-05    5.786603
2018-01-06    5.784011
2018-01-07    5.790133
2018-01-08    5.786967
2018-01-09    5.789944
2018-01-10    5.789299
Name: rolling_5d_avg, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Did you import `NumPy` for this, `np.random.seed(0)` ? could you please clarify a bit more with additional wording details. Thank you!

Comment: The average value is not correct, I manually tested it and the code value is wrong.

Comment: Hmmm.... `df['Value'].head(5 * 24 * 60).mean().round(6)` results in `5.786603`, matching the first number for Jan. 5.  To which average value are you referring?

Comment: For a given day, there are 24hours * 60minutes = 1440 data points. We then average 1140 * 5days = 7200. so, (7200 data point sums)/7200 = average of 5 days. But from what I am seeing, the value is off by 4-5 number.

Comment: In your data, or the sample data I've created above?  If the former, check to ensure that you are not missing data points (`df['Time'].diff().max()` should result in `Timedelta('0 days 00:01:00')`).  If the latter, reset the seed to 0 and copy the code above to ensure you get the same results.

Comment: In my data, the sample data is just a made up data. However, since we are only concerned with `TimeStamp in Minutes`, that is correct. So for each data we calculate 1140minutes data * 5days = 7200. And then, (7200 data point sums)/7200 is the average for that day. We do it for `each day` and not skipping any day as mentioned in the question.

Comment: This solution should do exactly what you just described in your comment above.

Comment: OK, I will look at it more carefully. Since I just plugged in your solution, it was giving off values by 4-5 points.

Comment: I think `'Value': abs(np.random.randn(len(time_idx))) + 5}` is causing wrong output. Can we not assign `'Value' : df["Value"] `?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195708/discussion-between-alexander-and-floss).